# How to left align bootstrap menu items when viewing on small screen?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

When a toggle button comes up on a small/mobile screen, I want the menu items left aligned as demonstrated upon re-sizing the screen in [this example](http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/step4.html).

Here is my current code. Can anyone help so that the menu items become automatically left aligned when viewed on small/mobile screen (on desktop screen, proportionately justified centered screen is desired)?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainnavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainnavbar">                  
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just google for `off canvas menu bootstrap`

Comment: This might be a good place to start http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/.

Comment: http://css3menu.com/eight-blue.html demonstrates left alignment when viewed on small screen but the question is how to achieve it in bootstrap. <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> can be changed to <ul class="nav nav-justified"> for justified display of the menu items.

Comment: changed to <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">